# Building Superset locally encounters missing static assets

Tags: npm, docker-compose, apache-superset

I'm trying to build [Superset](https://github.com/apache/superset) locally using `docker-compose`.

After cloning the repository, I modify `docker-compose.yml` so that it builds images from local source code instead of pulling from Docker Hub. My modifications include:

1. In service `db`, change Postgres image version from `image: postgres:14` to `image: postgres:10` since the service cannot be built properly with Postgres 14.
2. In services `superset`, `superset-init`, `superset-worker`, `superset-worker-beat` and `superset-tests-worker`, change `image: *superset-image` to `build: .` so that Docker builds the application from local source code.

However, after running `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up`, I got the blank screen like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE5E7.png). I checked out the logs and found out that a lot of asset files are missing, for example `/static/assets/images/loading.gif` is missing which results in that blank screen.

What am I wrong or missing from my configuration steps? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out, it's because the `webpackage` of the superset frontend is installed inside the container `superset_node` instead of while building it. That's why although the `superset_node` is built, we have to wait (in my case for about 15-20 more minutes) for the `webpackage` to be completely installed. Another point to note is that this installation takes up a lot of memory, so make sure you allocate enough RAM to it (in my case I allocate 16GB to Docker).